# Is there a way to duplicate a file WITH the metadata?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Sorry if this a noob question, but I'm just getting into Excel file management. Is there a way that when I try duplicating an Excel file that is saved in SharePoint (don't know if that is relevant), it'll also duplicate the metadata? When ever I duplicate a file, the metadata doesn't copy over...

Answer (score 0):

Is it the Doc Panel metadata you're not able to get? Because in Excel 2016, Document Panel was deprecated.

Comment: Yes. But we're using 2013 and 2007. Copying a file doesn't copy the metadata.